# D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile speed drops when not overwriting files

Tags: c++, io, directx, screenshot, direct3d

I am attempting to record my desktop screen with DirectX9.
For the first 120ish frames, it records at 60 FPS.
However, once it gets past that, it drops to 15 FPS.

But, if I set it to replace the same first 60 files/frames by changing `iTotalFrameCount` to `iCurrentFrameCount` in the file name I pass.

The framerate stays at 60 FPS.

What could be causing the file writing speed to drop so significantly if it is overwriting the same files on every run?

There is over 700 frames in that folder from the previous runs and it always overwrites them.

What makes the first 60 so special that they write fast?

```
bool TakeScreenShot(IDirect3DDevice9 *Device, char *FileName, int ScreenX, int ScreenY)
{
    static IDirect3DSurface9 *FrontBuffer = NULL; 

    HRESULT Result;

    IDirect3DSwapChain9* chain;



    if(FrontBuffer == NULL)
    {
        Result = Device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ScreenX, ScreenY, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &FrontBuffer, NULL);

        if(Result == D3DERR_INVALIDCALL)
            printf("Invalid call\n");

        if (Result != D3D_OK)
        {
            printf("Last error %d\n", GetLastError());

            return false;
        }
    }

    Device->GetSwapChain(0, &chain);

    chain->GetFrontBufferData(FrontBuffer);

    Result = D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(FileName, D3DXIFF_BMP, FrontBuffer, NULL, NULL);

    if (Result != D3D_OK)
        return false;

    return true;
}





static long long startTime;



// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{
    static DWORD dwTime = 0;

    static float fFrameRate;

    static int iCurrentFrameCount = 0,
                iTotalFrameCount = 0;


    if(startTime == 0)
        startTime = milliseconds_now();



    if(GetTickCount() - dwTime >= 1000)
    {
        stringstream sstream; 
        sstream << "Framerate: " << iCurrentFrameCount << endl;

        printf("%s\n", sstream.str().c_str());

        iCurrentFrameCount = 0;
        dwTime = GetTickCount();
    }


    stringstream sstream;

    sstream << "C:\\frames\\" << iTotalFrameCount << ".bmp";

    TakeScreenShot(d3ddev, (char*)sstream.str().c_str(), 1920, 1080);


    iCurrentFrameCount++;
    iTotalFrameCount++;


    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) != 0)
    {
        long long recordTime = milliseconds_now() - startTime;


        float seconds = recordTime / 1000.0f;


        float frameRate = (float)iTotalFrameCount / seconds;


        printf("FPS: %f\n", frameRate);


        Sleep(10000);

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: ``GetFrontBufferData`` is not fast. You are also calling ``CreateOffscreenPlainSurface`` every frame, which you can reuse (and ideally more than one for double buffering). ``D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile`` is also blocking. For screenshots every frame, you need to copy the data out of the offscreen surface and then have a writer on another thread so you don't keep blocking the rendering. For DX11, [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/ScreenGrab.cpp) is a good reference for the writing screenshots, but you are still using deprecated, legacy Direct3D 9 for some reason.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn good info, but has absolutely nothing to do with my question.

Comment: The first 60 are probably in your file system cache.

Comment: Recording  1920x1080@60 would produce `1920 * 1080 * 4 * 60 = 497664000 B/s = 0.5 GB/s` of uncompressed data. Is your disk fast enough to consume it? You may want to start using some compression.